# How to override aggregator_block_view() in the aggregator module?

Tags: 7, hooks, feeds, blocks

Can anyone tell me how to override aggregator_block_view in the aggregator module?

I have a feed I need to alter the html for and at the moment aggregator just turns the output into an unordered list.

I tried altering it in hook_item_list() but there was nothing for me to lock onto to identify the list as coming from the aggregator module.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to alter the block view you can try [hook_block_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_alter/7)

Refer to menu block alter example for an example

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21menu%21menu.module/function/menu_block_view_alter/7

---UPDATE---

```
  function hook_aggregator_process($feed) {
      foreach ($feed->items as $item) {
        mymodule_save($item);
      }
    }
```

Check out the docs at http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21aggregator%21aggregator.api.php/function/hook_aggregator_process/7

Also enable the aggregator settings at admin/config/services/aggregator/settings

----UPDATE-----

Also if you just want to override the item list then you should use `themename_preprocess_aggregator_summary_items(&$variables)` and check for 'summary_list' this holds the items list. For more details refer to `template_preprocess_aggregator_summary_items` in the `aggregator.pages.inc` file.

Comment: This doesn't work for the aggregation output as it just returns the pre-formatted html. I need to get in before it's made into a list.

Comment: checkout the updated answer

Comment: I tried this in my module and it doesn't seem to fire. Can I use this in a custom module?

Comment: Did you read the doc link ?? You need to activate the hook from the admin/config/services/aggregator/settings page for it to trigger.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I missed it when reading docs. I'm still not sure how to actually change the html that's output. Could you elaborate at all? I really appreciate your help so far.

Comment: you mentioned you want to alter the html. So for example if you want to make sure you want to limit the title to 255 characters then $item['title'] = truncate_utf8($item['title'], 255, TRUE, TRUE);. If you want more specific answer then you need to update your question with current output and the desired output so i know what exactly you want.

Comment: i have updated the answer with some more information.

Comment: I think `template_preprocess_aggregator_summary_items` is actually affecting the output for a feed aggregator source page, not the block.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED

My initial answer was off.  You may use the following to adjust the html around an individual item in your Feeds Aggregator Block:

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for an individual feed item for display in the block.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - item: The item to be displayed.
 *   - feed: Not used.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function theme_aggregator_block_item($variables) {
  // Display the external link to the item.
  return '<a href="' . check_url($variables['item']->link) . '">' . check_plain($variables['item']->title) . "</a>\n";
}
```

This resides in `aggregator.module`.  This still doesn't get at modifying `aggregator_block_view()` which is what puts the 'item' wrapping around each feed item.  I guess you could do a `hook_block_view($delta= '[the delta of the block you want to modify]')` and then copy the contents of the `aggregator_block_view` and modify the part where `theme('item_list')` is used and replace it with one of the other default wrappers (see some here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/group/themeable/7) or create your own?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the block that is automatically provided by Aggregator. Much easier to make your own block using Views.

1. Go to Views -> Add a New View
2. Show Aggregator Item
3. You can uncheck 'create a page' and check 'create a block' if you only want a block.
4. Give the block a name and Continue & edit
5. Under Fields, add the Aggregator Title and any other fields you want.

If you have multiple feeds, give them categories in the Aggregator settings (admin/config/services/aggregator), and then filter by category ID within the view.